# Pymongo way slower than MongoDB on the exact same query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a query that I'm running in both pymongo and Mongodb.
The bottleneck is most probably in the `$match` statement.
But it runs fine in MongoDB and gives me issues in Pymongo.

Query -

```
list(db.mentorbasicdetails.aggregate([
    
    {"$lookup":{
        "from":"colleges",
        "let":{
                     "college":"$educations.collegeId",
                     "profile":"$educations.profileTypeId"
              },
        "pipeline":[
            
          { "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                { "$eq": ["$patientId", "$$patientId"] },
                { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$college"] }
              ]
            }
          }},
            
            {"$project":
             
                 {
                 
                     "tier":{"$min":["$tier",3]},
                     "profile":"$$profile",
                     "_id":0
                 
                 }
            
            }
            
        ],
        "as":"collegetiers"
    }},   
]))
```

`pymongo.has_c()` returns True.

Takes around a minute to run in pymongo but ~2 secs for MongoDB.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Why is it so slow? and how can I optimize it to get better performance? Is it a library issue or a query issue?